# python mongodb update issue

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I am trying to update my document with python pymongo, the problem is update is not updating existing values with empty string. Here is what I am trying.

```
data = {
    "server_name": 'server_name',
     "ipaddr": '192.168.10.1',
     "conn_type": 'ssh',
     "login": "",
     "password": ""
}

collection.update({"_id": ObjectId(data['_id'])}, {'$set': data}, upsert=False, multi=False)
```

With the above code I want to set login and password as an empty but they were not changed and remain what they have existing values.

Would you please help me what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Try `collection.update({_id: ObjectId(data['_id'])}, {$set: data}, upsert=False, multi=False)`

Comment: Well my query is working fine, except not updating values with empty string, I can not remove quotes around $set because i am doing update with python script not directly on mongodb cursor

Comment: have you tried checking the WriteResult for errors, after the update?

Comment: hmm, yes there were nothing wrong

Comment: The "data" dictionary doesn't have the key "_id" perhaps that is the culprit. If it does, check that it matches the document you want to update and consider to edit your question.